Custom view based on res.partner subclass
I have 2 models that inherit from res.partner, using traditional class inheritance. Each subclass adds a few custom fields.
class PartnerExtA(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    field_a = fields.Char()

class PartnerExtB(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    field_b = fields.Char()

I need to customise the form view of each of these subclasses, and the make the customised view the default when the model is displayed.
For example, when displaying PartnerExtA, the res.partner form should look like:
name, phone, field_a   (and no other fields)

And when displaying PartnerExtB, the form should look like:
name, phone, field_b   (and no other fields)

I've tried playing with removing and adding fields using a pattern like this:
(I've removed the leading character from the xml tags as the forum was stripping the code otherwise :/ )
<record id="view_res_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.view.form.inherit.exta</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//group" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//group" position="after">
            <group invisible="not field_a">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="phone"/>
                <field name="field_a"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
   </field>
</record>
 

But things get complicated with the views interacting in strange ways.
Is there a better way to render a different view based on the concrete subclass in Odoo 17?
Any thoughts on this gratefully received...

This inheritence leads to one odoo model with both new fields. Odoo isn't using Python classes directly to setup it's models. If you really want to create submodels the way you know from python subclasses you have to set _name attribute on both (sub)classes different to the parent class and origin model. For example "res.partner.a" and "res.partner.b".

Another way doing something like different types and views for one model is to have "type" selection field on that model. There are some examples for such designs like account moves (account.move "move_type") or leads (crm.lead "type"), where the related (form) views are extremely dependent on these fields.

Little hint/advise to my last comment: don't do that on res.partner, because there is already a form view dependent field: is_company.

Hi @CZoellner thanks for the comments. I have also come to the conclusion that prototype inheritance using _name is the right way to go. Unfortunately that leads to other problems with res.partner. I created a new question here, and would really appreciate some help if you can! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78611568/odoo-17-prototype-inheritance-from-res-partner
