Odoo 17 prototype inheritance from res.partner
I'm trying to use Prototype inheritance from the res.partner model in Odoo 17.
class MyPartnerExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _name = 'my.partner.ext'

    custom_id = fields.Integer()

However, when I try to save an instance of this model, I get the following exception:
File "/Users/markns/workspace/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 3055, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for my.partner.ext.commercial_partner_id: my.partner.ext(4,)

I see some other questions related to this error: here, here and here but no solutions.
Is it possible (or recommended) to subclass res.partner with prototype inheritance (ie. _name + _inherit)?

I would probably use the delegation inheritance like in res.users.

Thanks, I've given up on prototype inheritance already, and have gone through delegation inheritance, only to give up on that too... https://www.reddit.com/r/Odoo/comments/1de6og4/display_custom_form_for_respartner_subclass_when/ So confused :/

Just make your own view for the submodels and don't show partner_idat all. You have all fields from partner. If you wan't custom views by opening the partner in your submodel form view, you can do that by providen a context on that field definition in the view. You have to add a context like {"form_view_ref": "my_module.my_partner_x_form_view"}. Submodels in either inheritance way come with ups and downs.
